# Ab initio m_dump command output to flat file with delimiter

Tags: ab-initio

I have a ebcdic file, I wanted to select only first 2 columns values in the output in the m_dump command
Output of m_dump values are like below:
[record
id  "100"
type_code  "20"
frstname  "abcd"
lastname "efgh"
new_line  "\n"]

or please help me to create a .dat file with delimiter from the output of m_dump command in ab initio

Comment: stil there.. which delimiter you want?

Answer (score 0):

Using `m_dump` command you can't print limited columns in the output.

But if you know old delimiter of a file, then you can use `tr` command and then write only required data into temp file, after that use `m_dump` command.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a RUN PROGRAM component and then drop unwanted fields with REFORMAT connected to the output port of RUN PROGRAM.

Saving the output to the file later would be straightforward with OUTPUT FILE.